# c# reading xml to listview

Tags: c#, xml, readxml, writexml

Write XML code

```
XmlTextWriter xmlchat = new XmlTextWriter("chatroomdoc.xml", UTF8Encoding.UTF8);
        xmlchat.WriteStartDocument();
        xmlchat.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
        xmlchat.WriteStartElement("Chat");
        foreach (ListViewItem one in lvmess.Items)
        {
            xmlchat.WriteStartElement("Client", one.SubItems[0].Text);
            xmlchat.WriteElementString("Nickname", one.SubItems[0].Text);
            xmlchat.WriteElementString("Message",one.SubItems[1].Text);
            xmlchat.WriteEndElement();
        }
        xmlchat.WriteEndElement();

        xmlchat.WriteEndDocument();
        xmlchat.Close();
```

This code is part of my client chat application it saves text messages into an xml file . I need to write a code that loads xml file to listview when you opened client.But i couldn't make read part right either lvmess.Items.Add fails because of while or when i do it outside while it works but only first items(obviously ) can anybody help me ?

This is Read File Code

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

        ListViewItem lis = new ListViewItem();
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("chatroomdoc.xml"))
        {
            int i =0;

            while (reader.Read())
            {

                    switch (reader.Name.ToString())
                    {
                        case "Nickname":
                            lis.Text=reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                        break;
                        case "Message":
                            lis.SubItems.Add(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                        break;
                    }
                //lvmess.Items.Add(lis);
                //i++;

            }

            lvmess.Items.Add(lis);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have created your ListViewItem outside of the while loop, and oon each iteration you just changed the data on the same ListViewItem. You should create a new item with each iteration and add it to your list so it could be used later. Something like this:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){

    //ListViewItem lis = new ListViewItem();
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("chatroomdoc.xml"))
    {
        int i =0;

        while (reader.Read())
        {
                ListViewItem lis = new ListViewItem();
                switch (reader.Name.ToString())
                {
                    case "Nickname":
                        lis.Text=reader.ReadElementContentAsString();
                    break;
                    case "Message":
                        lis.SubItems.Add(reader.ReadElementContentAsString());

                    break;
                }
                lvmess.Items.Add(lis);
            //i++;

        }

       // lvmess.Items.Add(lis);
    }
}
```

Comment: please provide some description for your answer.